Alternatives to JPSoft TCC/LE
I'm running the latest JPSoft TCC/LE available (14.00.9 x64) which started showing a system wide issue  after Windows 11 update to 24H2.
As I open a file with LIST the mouse pointer starts moving with an hysteresis, like the mouse pointer gliding on an ice surface (...). The motion of the pointer keeps going on some movements, making it hard to point at a specific point.
Note that if I have the TCC/LE window in the background the pointer keeps being erratic - that gave me hard time understanding which was the origin!
When I quit the LIST command the mouse pointer returns to normal behavior.
Since there's no update of the free TCC/LE in many years, an update of the free application looks impractical. Still I'm looking for anything that has any sense to try with TCC/LE.
What free alternatives are there to TCC/LE?

The extensions that JPSoftware made to the CMD language are mostly exclusive to their products. Other "enhanced command prompt" programs that I've tried are significantly different, and generally don't extend the language as much as TC/TCC did. It also appears that TCC/LE is no longer supported, although it can be downloaded; all of their products are now 30-day trial paid products.

A quick look at AlternativeTo.Net only lists things like PowerShell or various packages (e.g., MinGW, CygWin, etc) that contain bash or other *ix shells.

@JeffZeitlin right, many enhancements in TCC (as it was for the original 4DOS) aren't around in a single command processor, too bad. The only nice alternative found so far is Cmder, which at the same time let's me keep using TCC/LE, and nice CMD/*nix mixed commands; also has the great feature to save the consoles and paths for next run(!)

A note to my own issue: I fixed the LIST behavior disabling mouse wheel in TCC, from the OPTION dialog (shrug)
